# Object clipping/non-selectable after keyframing vertices

Tags: python, vertices, keyframes, select, clipping

If I start off with a cube (same global and local coordinates), I'm able to select it fine. However, after I keyframe its vertices elsewhere, I'm unable to select the cube while it's near the initial keyframes. Also, I get clipping when I zoom in too far or if I'm viewing it at some other angle towards the initial frames. Why is this and what can I do to avoid this?

[image]

```
import bpy

cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
verts = cube.data.vertices
 
for v in verts: 
    
    v.keyframe_insert("co", frame = 1)
          
    v.co.z += 8
         
    v.keyframe_insert("co", frame = 200)
```

Comment: I think it's a bug.

Comment: Darn. I've been trying to find a trick around this. It seems that it's not even associated with +-z. Instead, I think the objects selectable area is where the object is at during the final keyframes.  With the object selected towards the beginning keyframes, you can verify this by pressing numpad "." <--- period/dot. It'll bring you to where it's located at the final keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

Bizzarly enough, I found that the following script fixed this issue:

```
import bpy

def update_mesh(scene):   
    for v in verts: 
        v.co.z += 0
            
scene = bpy.context.scene
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
verts = cube.data.vertices
 
for v in verts: 
    v.keyframe_insert("co", frame = 1)
    v.co.z += 10
    v.keyframe_insert("co", frame = 200)
        
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(update_mesh)
```

It seems that specifically using the function `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append()` and passing into it a "dummy" function that accepts the scene, and does a null operation on the vertices, fixed this issue.

I tried many permutations of this script, some being: for the `update_mesh` function, placing the keyframing inside it, not looping through the verts into it, not passing the scene into it. I've also tried a few different ways to update the scene, which semi-fixes some issues, but not completely (able to select only when select box fully engulfs)